# Trapezium chunked text background and gradient color CSS

Tags: html, css

Anybody know how to styling a `text` with trapezium chunked background shape and gradient color with CSS?,

My goal is to achieve like this : [my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mu5s.png)

From my knowledge What I tried so far is:

```css
.trapesium {
  float: left;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 35px solid red;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.align {
  color: white;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.gradient {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue), linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue);
}
.break {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapesium">
   <div class="align">THEME</div>
</div>

<!--break space-->
<div class="break"></div>

<div class="gradient">THEME</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CSS`, `::after` creates a `pseudo-element` that is the last child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. We often use `::after` to add more style to an element.

```css
.gradient-btn {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue), linear-gradient(to left,  red, blue);
}
.gradient-btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 38px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0px solid #fff;
  border-left: 27px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-btn">THEME</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much @Viral, works like a charm